# jquery->tabletools->excel export shifts headers to the right

Tags: jquery, excel, export, datatables, tabletools

a serious problem we are facing is that the excel export of tables (jquery->datatables->tabletools) works fine if the tables are displayed without a scroll bar. If a horizontal scroll bar is needed the headers of the tables are transformed and some "\t" tokens are prepended and appended to the header's innerHTML. Thus the excel export shifts the headers in the excel file to the right, for each "\t" 1 column. Do you have an idea how to get rid of that and solve the problem?

Would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We found that the "\t" tokens were caused by the PHP loop creating the table headers in the template in a dubious way. So no JS error and nothing to do with jquery.